# Load personal imagery via Google Earth API

Tags: .net, gis, google-earth-plugin

Here are my requirements:

1. I need to work offline
2. I have my own imagery to load into Google Earth
3. I'd like to be able to use the Google Earth API to load my imagery from say a .NET app(I can already embed GE in my winform)

I have not figured out how to load non-google imagery via the GE API. Can this be done?

We currently use Arcmap. Load imagery, and then using a custom plugin load data in to Arcmap and render all from Arcmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your own imagery using the free API, using for example a groundOverlay.  However by design the free API is not designed for offline use (and additionally it's terms of use require, amongst other things, your app is free and available to anyone which may not be the case for your app).

If you need to have an entirely offline setup with the API you may wish to purchase and Enterprise license which comes with an offline loader for the API along with allowing you to build your own custom globe with entirely your own datasets.